# Получить координаты клика мыши на PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Как получить координаты клика мыши на PictureBox на форме WinForms?

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: WinForms, исправила вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, судя по всему, вам нужно подписаться на `MouseClick` (не на `Click` — у него нет мышиных координат). В получаемых [`MouseEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) есть `Location` или отдельно `X` и `Y`.

Если `p` — ваш `PictureBox`, то нужно что-нибудь такое:

```
p.MouseClick += OnPictureBoxClicked;
```

```
void OnPictureBoxClicked(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
{
    var location = args.Location;
    // у вас есть координаты клика относительно формы
}
```

Ну или упакуйте `OnPictureBoxClicked` в лямбду.

Comment: То есть координаты относительно формы, а не PictureBox?

Comment: @Арина: Вроде бы да: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.location(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Арина: Если нужно относительно `PictureBox`, можно использовать пару `Form.PointToScreen` + `PictureBox.PointToClient`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1478105/276994

Comment: @Арина `MouseClick` в аргументах передает координаты мыши относительно конрола который подписан на событие, т.е. если обработчик висит на форме - то координаты относительно формы, если на `PictureBox` - то относительно `PictureBox`

Comment: @rdorn: Хм, а в MSDN (ссылка во втором комментарии) вроде написано, что относительно формы всегда.

Comment: @VladD да видел, даже перепроверил в коде из-за этого. И на ReferrenceSource нет упоминаний о координатах формы, событие определено в классе Control, координаты читаются нативными методами из сообщений WinAPI. Да и не логично это, тогда уж проще было отдавать сразу координаты экрана и не париться.